# How to show/hide autocomplete pop-up in Colab using only the keyboard?

Tags: user-interface, google-colaboratory

I like having the autocomplete "tooltip" window readily available for those times when I don't know the function signature, but the rest of the time it just gets in the way.

I know it's possible to globally and persistently enable/disable autocomplete, but this is not what I want. Rather, I want to hit some key(s) like `TAB` to make the popup appear, and/or `ESC` to make the pop-up disappear.

1. How do I make the pop-up **disappear** using the keyboard?
2. How do I make a "hidden-by-default" pop-up **appear** using the keyboard?

A solution for either of these 2 questions would solve my problem.

[image]

[edit]
I'm using Vim keybindings, which seems to eat the default meaning of `ESC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot shows parameter hints, which should always be dismissed by pressing escape.

If dismissed, you can summon the parameter hints again using the keyboard shortcut Shift-⌘ space on OSX or Shift-Control space on other platforms.

Comment: With the default keybindings this is true, but I'm using Vim keybindings. Pressing escape just puts my cursor back into normal mode, but the parameter hints remain.

Comment: Oh! However, if I un-check "Automatically trigger code completions", then I can use `⌘+Shift+Space` (on osx) to bring up the tooltip. That's halfway to what I wanted, and maybe as good as I'll find.